# Regular Expression - Add a '0' if number is only decimal point

Tags: regex

Having a bit of trouble with some decimal numbers - due to a bug in my companies system I have a product file that has prices such as £50 displayed not as '50.00' but '50.0'

Now we have the ability to use regular expressions within our system so I'm looking for a way to add a '0' if the decimal point is only 1. Or alternatively if there is only 1 integer after the decimal point, add a zero.

Could anyone possibly help me in the right direction?

Help greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance.

Liam

Comment: You need to give more information about the system.  Are we talking about perl regular expressions?  Regexes in PHP?  Can we use sed on the command line?

Comment: Are you looking for a regular expression that only operates on the number, or on text containing the price?

Comment: If you're using any C-influenced language then I would suggest using printf for this.

Comment: The system is Java based and you can use placeholders and there is one with RegexMatches - you can't use replace, quite limited.

On the number would be great.

And apparently cannot be multi line :(

Comment: You are really going to have to provide some sample code with context of what you're trying to do for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system supports lookaheads then try this in regex Multiline mode

```
(\d\.\d)(?=\D|$)
```

and replace with `$10` or `\10` (depending on your system)

The content of `$1` is what has been matched in the first bracket.

See it here (and test it) [on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30124)

Comment: Thats brilliant as it works but I don't think it supports multi-line which is a shame, gives me an error.